# Error when running DPDK app on valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, dpdk

When I run my DPDK based app on valgrind, it cannot execute it and throws error

> ERROR: This system does not support "RDRAND". Please check that
>   RTE_MACHINE is set correctly.

My CPU supports RDRAND, still it is throwing the same error. For valgrind to support hugepages which are being used by my app, I'm using the following patched version of valgrind.
https://github.com/bisdn/valgrind-hugepages.git

Comment: Have the same issue. Patched version of valgrind used to work well with older DPDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem on a Haswell architecture CPU, and was able to fix it by modifying one of the makefiles to remove a handful of options.  Specifically, AVX/AVX2, RDRND, FSGSBASE, and F16C. You might need to remove other options that valgrind is balking at and recompile DPDK, it was an iterative process for me.  There's probably a more elegant way to do this using the .config file but I didn't find it.  See this patch:

```
diff -u dpdk-2.2.0-orig/mk/rte.cpuflags.mk dpdk-2.2.0/mk/rte.cpuflags.mk
--- dpdk-2.2.0-orig/mk/rte.cpuflags.mk^I2015-12-15 12:06:58.000000000 -0500
+++ dpdk-2.2.0/mk/rte.cpuflags.mk^I2016-08-24 08:53:22.911258783 -0400
@@ -69,26 +69,6 @@
 CPUFLAGS += PCLMULQDQ
 endif

-ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__AVX__),)
-CPUFLAGS += AVX
-endif
-
-ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__RDRND__),)
-CPUFLAGS += RDRAND
-endif
-
-ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__FSGSBASE__),)
-CPUFLAGS += FSGSBASE
-endif
-
-ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__F16C__),)
-CPUFLAGS += F16C
-endif
-
-ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__AVX2__),)
-CPUFLAGS += AVX2
-endif
-
 # IBM Power CPU flags
 ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__PPC64__),)
 CPUFLAGS += PPC64
```

Answer (score 3):

RDRAND was introduced on IvyBridge, you can build dpdk with a specific subset of instructions using "CONFIG_RTE_MACHINE".  For this case you can use SandyBridge as the machine.

Modify $RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/.config, set CONFIG_RTE_MACHINE="snb", and rebuild the DPDK library (make -C $RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET).

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to this problem. DPDK supports `EXTRA_CFLAGS` variable which you can use to specify your own flags for GCC. Initial makefile runs gcc with options `-dN -E` to check what is supported by the platform. If you want to disable some instruction sets, e.g. RDRAND, you can specify option

`export EXTRA_CFLAGS=-mno-rdrnd`

and this will disable RDRAND in built DPDK library binaries.